# PowerShell - Get-QADUser = 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: powershell, quest

I'm running a MySQL Query to update MS AD and output errors to a txt file. The code works fine but after a few minutes I get the error 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

Below is a short bit of the code.

```
Function Addmembers {

$query = "SELECT * FROM allstudents_groups"
$dtResult = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"

$hashOptions = @{ } 
$hashOptions["strServer"] = "servername"
$hashOptions["strDatabase"] = "DB"  
$hashOptions["strUser"] = "user"
$hashOptions["strPassword"] = "pass"
$hashOptions["strQuery"] = $query
$dtResult = executeMYSQLQuery($hashOptions) 
$OU = "OU=Class Group,DC=company,DC=internal"

ForEach ($row in $dtResult){
    $result = $row.GroupName
    $resmember = $row.Members
    $out_file = "C:\Scripts\Users.txt"
    $studentOU = "OU=Users,OU=CHS,OU=Est,DC=Company,DC=internal"
    $resmember | %{$_.Split(',')} | %{
        If(Get-QADUser -PageSize 1000 -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -SizeLimit 0 -SearchRoot "$studentOU" -LdapFilter "(name=$_)")
        {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $result -Members "$($_)"
        [System.GC]::Collect()
    }

Else
    {"$_" | out-file "$out_file" -append}
}}
[System.GC]::Collect()
}
$dtResult = $Null
}
Addmembers
```

I believe this is due to the code getting all the DB stuff and trying to hold it in memory. I think a ForEach-Object would stop the memory from filling up but that doesn't seem to support logic. I've also tried adding a [System.GC]::Collect() within the IF statement but that does nothing to stop the RAM from creeping up

Comment: What happens if you do pipe it directly, $dtResult = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable" | foreach ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

Putting a carriage return and an output line seems to handle the job much better and completes the whole DB table.

```
        If(Get-QADUser -PageSize 1000 -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -SizeLimit 0 -SearchRoot "$CLVOU" -LdapFilter "(name=$resteach)")
        {
        Write-Output "$resteach is being added to $result"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $result -Members "$resteach"
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are storing your entire result set in this variable: `$dtResult`

So, assuming it is a large recordset, it could easily consume all of your memory. You might try something like the below. Foreach-Object would send each object down the pipe as it comes in, rather that trying to hold it all in memory and then iterate over it.

```
executeMYSQLQuery($hashOptions) | Foreach-Object {
   $result = $_.GroupName
   $resmember = $_.Members

   #etc...


}
```